# why publishing to facebook wall using graph api results authenication error in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My iOS app is live and I have used Facebook Graph API for publishing the post but suddenly i am getting complain that post sharing gets fail.I have checked with facebook developer forum and they are talking about i need to add one more permission for that which i added but still i am getting same error.Here I am posting my code what i have did it for publishing on facebook wall.Please share some ideas on that.

```
if ( (self.fbGraph.accessToken == nil) || ([self.fbGraph.accessToken length] == 0) ) {
            [self.fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:)andExtendedPermissions:@"email,publish_stream,public_profile,user_checkins,publish_actions,status_update,user_friends,read_stream,user_photos,friends_photos"];
        }
        else
        {
            if([self.fbGraph.accessToken length] > 0){
                NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];
                NSString *Header;
                if(self.AutoMatedSahre==100){
                    Header=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@ is planning to use this offer'\n%@",[[self.shareDelegate.userdetails  valueForKey:@"firstname"] capitalizedString],[self.dForDetail valueForKey:@"business_name"]];
                }else{
                    Header=[self.dForDetail valueForKey:@"business_name"];
                }

                  NSString *dealdesc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ offer on ABC.\n %@.\n http://www.example.com/deal_summary.html?deal_id=%@",[self.dForDetail valueForKey:@"business_name"],[self.dForDetail valueForKey:@"deal_name"],[self.dForDetail valueForKey:@"id"]];
                [variables setObject:dealdesc forKey:@"message"];
                [variables setObject:Header forKey:@"name"];
                [variables setObject:[self.dForDetail  valueForKey:@"image_url"] forKey:@"link"];
                FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [self.fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/feed" withPostVars:variables];
                NSLog(@"postMeFeedButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
                //parse our json
                SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
                NSDictionary *facebook_response = [parser objectWithString:fb_graph_response.htmlResponse error:nil];
                [parser release];
                self.feedPostId = (NSString *)[facebook_response objectForKey:@"id"];
```

I am getting following Response:

> postMeFeedButtonPressed:  {"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't
>   authorized the application to perform this
>   action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get approval from facebook by resubmitting or submitting your app with review again the permission is `publish_action` check facebook dev documentation about this particular permission and you will get the process needed for submitting for a review.
Here is the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions)

Comment: on the above sample code I have added publish_action Permission on authenticateUserWithCallbackObject function.

Comment: Specifying permission doesn't let you access anything. As Saheb said, you need to get an approval. Submit your app for review.

Comment: hmm ok i got it now.Thank you.